# what does SomeString.equals("\"D")) means?

Tags: java, string, equals

I would like know how the following scenario works.

```
String test = "a,b,c";

String testary[] = test.split(",");
```

`if(!testary[0].equals("\"D"))` gives?

I want to know why we are using backslash along with some char and how does the above statement works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the escape sequence. It tells interpreter to decipher it an an " instead of end to string. This might help
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 5):

When you're writing a string literal, you put it in double quotes (`"`). If you want to put an actual `"` character *in* the string, you have to put a backslash (`\`) before it so the parser knows that it's part of the string, not the ending quote. This is called "escaping" the quote character.

So the line

```
if(!testary[0].equals("\"D"))
```

tests whether the string at index 0 of the `testary` array does *not* equal the string `"D` (a double quote followed by the capital letter D). (The "not" part of that is the `!` at the beginning.)

Answer (score 3):

with the  `\` you are actually escaping the `"` that is just after the `\` , so equals will test against `"D`